# How do I input symbols from the International Phonetic Alphabet?

Tags: support, editing, markdown

How do I input symbols from the International Phonetic Alphabet?
I have looked at the [Editing Help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help) but there is nothing about it.

Comment: I hope these answer your question. https://stackapps.com/questions/3828/ipa-keyboard-for-linguistics-se https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-to-enter-phonetic-transcriptions

Comment: Ah. I thought there would be some kind of special syntax using plain ASCII, kinda like MathJax or LaTex.

Comment: In addition to @Glor's answer, here's one handy tool shared a few years ago in chat that I've kept around: http://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/

Answer (score 4):

Some IPA symbols have HTML entity codes with more or less logical names/abbrevations, so you can type them in plain ASCII:

- `&aelig;` becomes æ
- `&eth;` becomes ð
- `&ntilde;` becomes ñ

But most of them, like the schwa, only have numbers, which will be hard to remember:

- `&#601;` becomes ə

A full list is available [here](https://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-charts/ipa-symbols-with-html-codes/).

Answer (score 3):

For an occasional user, the keyboard linked to by M.A.R. would be my suggestion:

http://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/

If you want to type a lot of IPA, it might be more convenient to install the Keyman IPA layout on your computer:

https://keyman.com/keyboards/sil_ipa

This is free and cross-platform, and you can even try it out right in your browser!  But make sure you read [the docs](https://help.keyman.com/keyboard/sil_ipa/1.8.2/sil_ipa) first, since you probably won't be able to figure out how to use it just by guessing.

(If you search online you might find recommendations for KMFL or Ekaya – essentially free alternatives to Keyman – but thanks to SIL International, the Keyman software is now free on all platforms, so you don't need to download KMFL or Ekaya anymore.)